# Chose initial time with TimePicker (not currentTime)

Tags: android, timepicker

I have a TimePicker in a Dialog. But what I want is to initiate it with value that I chose and not with current time. I don't know how to do it.

Here is my Java code :

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.reminder_edit, null);
    dialog.setTitle("Fréquence des notifications");
    timepicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    timepicker.setIs24HourView(true);
    int hour =2;
    timepicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
    timepicker.setCurrentMinute(0);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Here is my XML code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
</TimePicker>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Annuler" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the dialog and assigning it the view.  But then you inflate a new view and manipulate the contents.  To actually change the TimePicker owned by the dialog you will have to retrieve it.

```
timepicker picker = (TimePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
```